# Run projects from androidviews

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-custom-view

I am trying to run the sample project from  [customviews](http://www.androidviews.net/) but facing some problems. i am not able to run any project from the site. Each time getting different type of error. I also searched in the net for the solution but failed to figure out the solution. May be i am facing a general problem for all projects and if i solve one i may be able to solve the others.
In ActionbarPullRequest library i am getting :

```
Description Resource Path Location Type        SmoothProgressBar cannot be resolved to a type   DefaultHeaderTransformer.java   /library_ActionbarPulltoRefresh/src/uk/co/senab/actionbarpulltorefresh/library  line
57  Java Problem
```

In StackBlurDemo i am getting this error :

```
Description Resource Path Location Type  toggleButtonMode cannot be resolved or is not a field  MainActivity.java   /StackBlurDemo/src/com/example/stackblurdemo    line 30 Java Problem
```

Comment: Are you using any library projects, have you checked the export private libraries in build path

Comment: Yes Check selected all  the libraries in the java buildpath.